# In Logic, is it possible to convert multiple imported audio tracks into one track with multiple takes?

Tags: logic

I recorded our singer at his house on GarageBand on his laptop the other day. We did multiple takes of a few songs, and it would be very helpful if I could turn those multiple discrete tracks into a single track with multiple takes and comp that way.

After a couple of hours on google I'm starting to think I'll have to suck it up and comp the way I would in GB, but it's worth asking just in case.

I have Logic on a Mac Mini, we had limited time, and I didn't want to spend part of it setting up my computer in his house. Next time we'll record at my house, or deal with bringing my Mac to his house.